# Find a specific directory on Apache server

Tags: php, apache, fileserver

I have access to the server in question. I know the name of the directory I'm looking for on the server, but don't know the full path to it.

Is there a way for me to retrieve the full file path to the directory by using the the directory name?

**Edit: I don't have shell access.**

Answer (score 1):

if you have shell access you can use `find` like the following

```
find / -type d -name DIRECTORYNAME
```

where / is the search starting point and replace DIRECTORYNAME obviously, also try `man 1 find` for more information.

Comment: My bad, I should have mentioned I do not have shell access. I'll update the question.

Comment: what kind of access do you have? are you able to upload a php script for example and execute it under the webserver's process?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `locate` command

`locate DirectoryName`

Its format is something like this

`locate [option] [search-pattern]`

Note: In the command below, the option --basename or -b tells locate to only match the file (directory) basename (which is exactly pkg) but not the path (/path/to/pkg). Where \ is a globbing character, it disables the implicit replacement of pkg by *pkg*.

```
locate --basename '\pkg'
```